# webpackChunkName not being honored in CRA application

Tags: webpack, create-react-app

I'm doing a dynamic import as follows:

```js
import(
    /* webpackChunkName: Bar */ 
    '@aspnet/signalr'
).then(({HubConnectionBuilder, HttpTransportType}) => {
    ...
})
```

The imported library does get chunked separately, but the chunk in the production build isn't named per the [magic comment](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments)... Any idea why this could be? This is a non-ejected CRA app using v3.4.3 of `react-scripts`.

NB: I've opened an issue on the create-react-app repo [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10349)

Comment: My need was to be able to separate out one specific package from the vendor chunk. As a workaround for now, I've been able to do that by overriding CRA's webpack config using `react-app-rewired` and creating a dedicated cacheGroup for that package.